# Rotate image between 2 degree values

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I'm using [jQueryRotate](http://jqueryrotate.com/) to rotate my image.

Basically I want the image to start at 0 then rotate to -20 degrees then to 15 degrees then keep going back and forth between these 2 values and continue this infinitely.

So basically a little image shake, would this be possible with jQueryRotate or would you recommend another jquery plugin? Would need something with IE9 support.

Comment: What you have tried. Append code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry forgot to post the code, but I was able to come up with a solution.

```
 function() {
 var rotation = function() {
     $("#img1").rotate({
         duration: 1000,
         angle: 0,
         animateTo: -15,
         callback: function() {
             $(this).rotate({
                 duration: 1000,
                 angle: -15,
                 animateTo: 0,
                 callback: function() {}
             });
         }
     });
 }
 rotation();
```